# How to get the Text of a paragraph in realtime of a Google DOC?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

i am building A Google Doc addon, how can i get the text of a paragraph that a user is currently (realtime) is writing from a google DOC.

I tried that :

```
var cursor1  = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getCursor();
var element1 = cursor1.getElement();
var mytext2  = element1.asParagraph();
var mytext3  = mytext2.getText();
```

but sometimes is getting blank text?

P.

Answer (score 0):

You can not get in realtime in Google Doc as there is no onEdit() trigger available for Docs. Use [Realtime API](https://developers.google.com/drive/realtime/).

Comment: Well actually i have a while loop with an interval looking for the text of the paragraph. Although most of the times this actually works sometimes a get a empty text and sometimes a get the text of the next paragraph. I dont know why this happens...?

Thanks anyway.

Comment: But my guess is that's not a correct way to get realtime data in Google Doc. If you want to get realtime data, you need edit trigger so you can those realtime data. But Google Doc doesn't have that trigger. It is available only for spreadsheet. But still, would you mind sharing your while loop's code to look at it? I may help more after looking at it.

Comment: i am trying to build a text mining tool for google docs. I have a call of a function with an interval time using javascript.